# Forming clubs with an odd number of members, with each pair of clubs having an even number of members in common

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

> Suppose we have a town with $n$ residents who love forming groups. To limit the number of groups, the town head decided: 1) **Every club must have an odd number of members**, and 2) **Any two clubs must *share* an even number of members**. Show that it is not possible to form more than $n$ clubs.

There's a hint provided:

> First try to find maximum number of subsets of the set $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$ so that for any two subsets $A_i$ and $A_j$ we have $|A_i\cap A_j|=k$. Now use and extend this idea.

I have no idea on how to prove the hint as well, and although the main problem and this hint look "similar", I cannot see a direct extension.

I tried the following way for the hint: Let subset $A_i$ be represented by a vector $v^i=(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ with $v_r=1$ if person $r$ is in that group and $0$ otherwise. Then $|A_i\cap A_j|=(v^i)'(v^j)=k$ for every $i\neq j$. So we want to find the number of possible $v^i$ such that $(v^i)'(v^i)\leq n$ for each $i$ and $(v^i)'(v^j)=k$ for each $i\neq j$.

I have no idea how to proceed. Can you help me with both the hint and the original question, please?

Comment: Any help, anybody?

Comment: Assuming club=group, here's a dumb question: If we have n+1 clubs and n residents, how would we have that every club must have an odd number of members? If we have 1 resident per club, then 1 club has 0 members and hence an even number. Same thing I think for n+2 and so on.

Comment: You need to find "minimum" number of groups. That's why the story has been given: people love to form groups but the headman limits the no. of groups to be formed.

Comment: Landon Carter, I don't follow. What do you mean exactly? Also, I'm not sure you answered my dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ **Every club must have an odd number of members**, and

$2)$ **Any two clubs must *share* an even number of members**.

Show that it is not possible to form more than $n$ clubs.

---

Let $C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_m$ be $m$ clubs satisfying $1)$ and $2)$.

For each $C_i$, let $x_i$ be its $(0,1)$-characteristic vector.

The characteristic vectors are a $n$-dimensional vectors, which components corresponds to a resident, and has value $1$ if he is in the club, and $0$ if not.

The dot product $x \cdot y$ of two of these vectors is the size of the intersection of the corresponding sets.

Rules $1)$ and $2)$ can now be written

$$
\begin{align}
 & 1) \: x_i \cdot x_i \:\: \text{is odd} \\
 & 2) \: x_i \cdot x_j \:\: \text{is even}, \: \text{for} \: i \neq j \\ 
\end{align}
$$

In modulo $2$

$$
\begin{align}
 & 1) \: x_i \cdot x_i = 1  \\
 & 2) \: x_i \cdot x_j = 0, \:\: \text{for} \:\: i \neq j \\ 
\end{align}
$$

If these vectors are linearly independent there can be at most $n$, since they are $n$-dimensional.

Suppose that for some scalars $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_m$

$$c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + ... + c_m x_m = 0$$

Now, for any $i$, take the dot product of both sides with $x_i$.  Because of
rule $2)$ everything cancels out, except for:

$$c_i x_i \cdot x_i = c_i = 0$$

Hence all the $c_i$'s are $0$, and the vectors are linearly independent, which proves the claim.

Comment: This method is quite common and standard, it seems. Can you please cite a reference to learn this?

Comment: Linear Algebra methods in Combinatorics by Babai

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is little problem with JKnecht solution.

Use of modulo 2 is not fully correct without additional explanation, because coefficients $c_i$ can be non-integer.

Let's see at the matrix $a_{ij}=x_i\cdot x_j$ with integer elements.

If
$c_1x_1+c_2x_2+...+c_mx_m=0$ then product of matrix $a_{ij}$ and vector
$c_j$ should be zero vector. This is system of linear equations with zero right part that has non-zero solutions only if determinant of the matrix is equal to zero.

Determinant of matrix $a_{ij}$ is non-zero because it is congruent to 1 modulo 2.

That's why the only solution of $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+...+c_mx_m=0$ is all $c_i=0$.